# Java / Android: Collect all Button methods in Helper class

Tags: java, android, button

Heyho.

Is it possible that I put all onClick() Methods in a single class to have a better Overview?

That's what I've tried:

```
public class ButtonHandler extends MainActivity
{
    public ButtonHandler()
    {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void OnClick1(View v)
    {
       if (_inputTextView != null)
       {
           _inputTextView.append("1");
       }
    }
}
```

But this gives me the following Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.fayt.taschenrechner, PID: 4009
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method OnClick1(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btn_1'
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Is that even possible or am I trying something impossible?

Greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app crash is because you pass your `view` as parameter. Currently you are setting `android:onClick` which there is no parameter in android system which will cause `IllegalStateException`. Learn how to make `onClick` programatically then you could put all your event inside on class. You could simply create another java class inside your project for handle all the click event rather than extends a mainActivity .

Comment: Works fine now. Thank you very much.